# How to transform KML from lon-lat to UTM (E-N), using Python?

Tags: python, kml, utm

I have a lot of KML files set as lon-lat (geographic coordinates) and want to set them as UTM (E-N) and WGS84 with Python (using arcpy, ogr, or gdal)

Does anyone knows how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I think KML only uses Long-Lat coordinates (EPSG codes 3857 or 900913). You can try reprojecting to your local UTM projection and save them as another format (e.g. Shapefile, or GeoJSON or whatever). `ogr2ogr` should work for you:

```
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile " -s_srs "EPSG:3857" -t_srs "EPSG:XXXXX" \
       output_file.shp my_kml_file.kml
```

where XXXXX is the EPSG code from your target projection (go [here for clues](http://spatialreference.org/) as to what code to use)

Comment: Long-Lat should be EPSG:4326 (WGS84). EPSG:3857 and 900913 are in (not real) metres.